# AttributeError: type object 'Graph' has no attribute 'edges_list'

Tags: oop, graph, attributeerror

I'm trying to create a graph with OOP.
I'm getting an error `AttributeError: type object 'Graph' has no attribute 'edges_list'` and I don't understand why. Here's the code:
I would love some help.
I did set an attribute to Graph called edges_list. why can't it find it?

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges_file):
        self.node_set = set() #Set of nodes by name
        self.edges_list = []
        self.edges_file = edges_file
        self.generate_graph(edges_file)


    class Node:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.metal = -1

    class Edge:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.side1 = 0
            self.side2 = 0
            self.resistance = 0

    def generate_graph(self, edges_file):
        G = nx.Graph()
        G.add_nodes_from(range(0,856284))
        nodes_file = open('nodes.csv','r') 
        nodes_file_content = nodes_file.readlines()
        with open('edges.csv', 'r') as edges_file:
            next(edges_file)
            for line in edges_file:
                splitted_line = line.split(",")
                edge_name = splitted_line[0]
                node_name = splitted_line[1]
                neighbor_name = splitted_line[2]
                new_edge = self.Edge(edge_name)
                new_edge.side1 = splitted_line[1]
                new_edge.side2 = splitted_line[2]
                self.edges_list.append(new_edge.name)
                self.node_set.add(self.Node(node_name).name)
                self.node_set.add(self.Node(neighbor_name).name)
        edges_file.close()
        nodes_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph = Graph('edges.csv')
    Graph.generate_graph(Graph,'edges.csv')
```

Comment: You will get better response if you tag your question correctly.  Always tag with the coding language - this looks like python.  The graph tag is wrong - did you read the tag description before adding it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you added the files edges.csv and nodes.csv. Without it it's more of a wild suggestion
It looks like one of the issues is in your second run line: `Graph.generate_graph(Graph,'edges.csv')`

Instead, try running the code with:
`graph.generate_graph(r'.\edges.csv')`

Also, in def generate_graph, this line is wrong:

```
with open('edges.csv', 'r') as edges_file
```

That is because you're inside a function that doesn't know the filename yet. You want to write it:`with open(edges_file, 'r') as file:`
Of course, change the rest of the code as needed...

Hope this helps!
Good luck